# how to add the already created keychain key to provisioning profiles

Tags: objective-c, certificate, keychain, ios-provisioning

I have created my own key (public/private) via keychain access.
But my company already have created a provisioning profile and developer certificate,which i downloaded (after logging) and installed it in my Xcode and iPhone as well.
But when i try to run on iPhone,it says "There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain".
I have also set bundle identifier name correctly in info.plist,but what am i doing wrong?
Is it that i should somehow add my own mac key pairs to somewhere as to match it since it is already created by company?
Could anyone help or suggest where m i going wrong,i have searched forums they all are simply not matching my problem and misleading other ways.

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the private key for the developer certificate that you have downloaded. The error *"There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain"* means you don't have the private key.

You say *"my company already have created a [...] developer certificate"*, which sounds like they have created a developer certificate for you. If that is the case, they need to send you the private key because you won't have this by default.

Generally it should be up to each individual developer to make a certificate signing request and gerenate the development certificate in the provisioning portal. There's no reason for the company to do that for you.